# Terminal autocompletion freezes the UI on a fresh Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, freeze, zsh, autocomplete

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a pretty powerful desktop.

When I open the terminal and type

```
ls /<TAB><TAB>
```

The cursor stops blinking and the whole UI is frozen. Only the mouse can move. It lasts between 0,5s and 3s depending on the moment.

I tried to install zsh. It has the exact same behavior than bash.

Following this [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/581007/bash-autocompletion-is-slow-freezing-my-desktop#) I tried the `set -vx` thing. It stills freeze, but nothing more on my console about it.

Comment: Same using sakura. Same issue with `l<TAB><TAB>` (which shows the list of the commands after 3s).

Comment: Did you do all the Ubuntu Updates (lots of these). ls <tab>  <tab> immediately shows me the ls output

Comment: The Software Updates tool tells my computer is up to date. Obviously I tried to restart too

Comment: I just did 10 MB of updates and I was up to date a day or two ago. Try restarting

Comment: I restarted, sudo apt upgrade is `0 newly installed` and Software Updater tells `The software on this computer is up to date`

Comment: I am not sure what else could cause this.  Try sudo ls <tab>

Comment: `sudo su` `root@ubuntu:/ ls <TAB><TAB>` . Same issue but nice try :) Testing my disk now (it's a SSD, I doubt it has mechanical issues but...)

Comment: Disk is ok. I just noticed that 3 letters or more are working well.
`np<TAB><TAB> ...2s... npm` whereas
`yar<TAB><TAB> ...instant... yarn`. Same with `na` vs `nan` for the nano command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105172/discussion-between-maxime-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seems that following the steps in that issue solved the problem:  [No sound device detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882198/no-sound-device-detected)

Visual Studio Code also warned me about fs.inotify.max_user_watches being to low when I opened a big Python project.

So I think adding this configuration to `/etc/sysctl.conf` is what solved the issue.

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

May also be related to force-reloading alsa, but I can't see how this can be related !I can't reproduce my initial case by setting the max_user_watches to 8192 again, so not 100% sure about my solution

**EDIT 1 week later**

I know better what was going on. I have an advanced audio interface that I use on Windows. When I plug it using Ubuntu, I have no audio output (not even the basic one on my computer). Fixing that issue by not connecting it when using Ubuntu gave my native audio back and resolved this autocompletion issue.

**EDIT 1 month later**

I just froze the UI by pluging my Tascam US-122 MKII. I don't know how this can happen, but be aware that pluging an unsupported device can cause the terminal or Visual Studio Code to behave weirdly without getting any explicit error.